# What modbus library should I use for modbus protocol for GCC

Tags: gcc, modbus

We are building a product, which requires modbus communication (both rs-485 and TCP/IP). The code has to run on an embedded device which has Linux running on it. We have following criteria for the selecting the library that we would be using.

1. It has to be opensource, since we are opensource geeks.
2. We would give this product to our users and what their application would be we are not aware, hence it has to complete implementation of the modbus protocol.
3. Wide user base: What we believe is that greater the users of the code, more the stability of the code.

I came across two such libraries:

http://www.freemodbus.org

and

[libmodbus](http://pes.free.fr/)

Are there any more modbus libraries. Please suggest with pros and cons

Comment: which one is more configurable?it is critical for real embedded has say 1K of RAM on a whole system

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest libmodbus, it works well and is cross platform.

http://www.libmodbus.org

Comment: Is there a library with c++ API?

Answer (score 0):

I am just starting to explore these options as well. My priority is on ease of use which has led me to [RModBus](http://rmodbus.heroku.com/) since it was the only one that I was able to get immediate results with. However, there is also a Python library, Pymodbus, that appears to be quite complete in implementation.

I'm sorry, I just figured out that GCC is a compiler; my answer is way off topic.

Again, I was looking for a scripting language that my noob self could be more comfortable in. It really came down to a question of language rather than the library itself. Oh, I am only using the TCP/IP stack at this time, which somewhat simplifies it as well.